# In searching algorithm, if number is found function returns index. If not found, should it return None or False?

Tags: python, boolean, nonetype

Let's say I have a method for linear search in ordered list. If it founds the number, it returns the index of that number. If not found, should it return False or None ?

```
def sequentialSearchOrderedList(inList: list, number: int) -> Union[int, bool]:
    if not inList:
        return False

    for i in range(len(inList)):
        print('NUMBER:', inList[i])
        if inList[i] == number:
            return i
        if inList[i] > number:
            return False
    return False
```

or

```
def sequentialSearchOrderedList(inList: list, number: int) -> Union[int, None]:
    if not inList:
        return None

    for i in range(len(inList)):
        print('NUMBER:', inList[i])
        if inList[i] == number:
            return i
        if inList[i] > number:
            return None
    return None
```

I tried both, but I am not sure which option is better practically.

Comment: Implement both, as `find` (returns an index or -1) and `contains` (returns a boolean).

Comment: The return value should be just `int` (for a "find index of" function, where it returns the index or `-1`) or just `bool` (for a "does this list contain" function, where it returns `True` or `False` depending on whether or not the list contains the value.

Comment: `False` would be a bad idea, because it compares equal to zero, using the `==` operator.

Comment: thanks you everyone, regarding to your comments I understand it's better to keep returning value as one type(index if found, -1 if not found). But if in a condition we should return at least two types, which one is better?